# Can I call wordpress functions only in theme files with supported names?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a file called, nl.php inside my wordpress theme folder and when I try to call a function like wp_header or any function, i get an error message, that the function does not exist.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to load the wp-load.php file, which will then allow you to call wordpress functions.

For example:

```
require( '../wordpress/wp-load.php' );
```

with 'wordpress' being your install root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the core Wordpress files.

```
<?php require 'wordpresspath/wp-blog-header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: In this case you might also want to use `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);`, or you'll get all sorts of awkward problems. Much better just to use `wp-load.php` imho.